# COCI 2006 Contest#1 Bond task explanation

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Task : http://hsin.hr/coci/archive/2006_2007/contest1_tasks.pdf

I read the solution but I don't understand any bit operation shown here:

```
/*
  Croatian Open Competition in Informatics 2006/2007
  Contest 1 - Task BOND
  Programming language C++
*/

#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int n;
double prob[21][21];

char vec_rijesio[1<<21];
double memo[1<<21];

double rijesi( int d, int s ) {
   if ( d == n )
      return 1.0;

   if ( vec_rijesio[s] ) return memo[s];
   vec_rijesio[s] = 1;
   double &ret = memo[s];
   ret = 0.0;

   for ( int i=0; i<n; ++i )
      if ( ( s & (1<<i) ) == 0 ) {
         double tmp = prob[d][i] * rijesi(d + 1, s|(1<<i));
         if ( tmp > ret ) ret = tmp;
      }

   return ret;
}

int main() {
   scanf( "%d", &n );

   for ( int i=0; i<n; ++i )
      for ( int j=0; j<n; ++j ) {
         int x;
         scanf( "%d", &x );
         prob[i][j] = x / 100.0;
      }

   double ret = rijesi( 0, 0 );
   printf( "%.6f\n", ret*100.0 );

   return 0;
}
```

Could someone please explain the code for me?
1. What does "1<<21" mean? 
2. What happened in the for loop inside rijesi()? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's a worse-is-better exponential-time algorithm for maximum-weight perfect matching that uses dynamic programming with a table indexed by the set of missions already taken, represented as an integer.

Comment: Pretty uninteresting with *N < 20*. With *N < 50* or so you would at least need to see that you can apply the logarithm and then use any min-cost matching algorithm, even a very inefficient one.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. 1<<21 mean 2^21 using bitwise left shift operation.
> 2. The algorithm is basically brute force with memoization where it tries assigning each task for a given jimmy bond and check the
>      resulting probability and evaluating maximum of them all.